# How to pass a function pointer to a function with variable arguments?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I don't know how to accomplish this!

how to get the function pointer in va_list arguments?

thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a typedef for the function pointer type.

Answer (score 5):

Typedefs often make working with function pointers easier, but are not necessary.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
void foo(int count, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    int i;
    va_start(ap, count);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        void (*bar)() = va_arg(ap, void (*)());
        (*bar)();
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Comment: In general, to create a type name (for use with `va_arg`, `sizeof`, a typecast or similar), write a declaration of a variable with that type, then remove the variable name.

Comment: Actually, this is (ironically) they only time that typedefs are required. Speaking of the *type* parameter for va_arg in section 7.15.1.1 of the C Standard: "The parameter type shall be a type name specified such that the type of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can be obtained simply by postfixing a * to type." This means that many non-trivial types aren't guaranteed to work, including your example, without a typedef.

Comment: Doesn't compile on my toolset.

Comment: Yeah, a couple hours after I wrote this I thought about whether it was legal, and then "well, it works with GCC..."  Oh well, caf's comment is useful regardless of this particular answer.

Comment: ...except strike `va_arg` from the examples I gave.